# How to add 'uniq -c' results and continuously overwrite in a loop?

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I'm writing a shell script and I'd like to combine the results of the unique values and their counts one file at a time. For example, if I am reading the data from the the two files below (with the number in the first column being the unique count):

**Data Read in First Loop**

```
3 Dog   
1 Cat   
5 Horse
```

**Data Read in Second Loop**

```
1 Dog  
3 Cat  
1 Horse  
2 Goat
```

I would want the second and first file to be combined in order to overwrite the my "tally file" as:

**Resulting File after 2nd Loop Completes**

```
4 Dog  
4 Cat  
6 Horse  
2 Goat
```

I'm trying to accomplish this because the data set is large and I would rather read and delete the files than download (or `cat` the files all together and find the `uniq -c` at the end since the file would be very long). Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses `awk` to do the summing on a tempfile `tallytmp` and a running tally named simply `tally`. I'm `sort`ing the two tally files together on the second field (`-k2`)

It needs a blank file `tally` to start with, so `touch tally`, then for each iteration:

```
uniq -c file > tallytmp
sort -k2 tally tallytmp \
  |awk '{
          if($2==prev){
            tot+=$1
          }else{
            print tot,prev;
            tot=$1;pc=$1;prev=$2
          }
        }END{
          print tot,prev
        }' > tallyresult
cp tallyresult tally
```

(Go ahead, put the `awk` script on a single line.)

Logically I should be able redirect the `sort|awk` pipeline directly to `tally`, but `sort` was still using it, so it clobbers it; hence the second tempfile `tallyresult` before copying that over our results file, `tally`.

Output of this on the two supplied iterations is actually:

```
[blank line]
4 Cat
4 Dog
2 Goat
6 Horse
```

The ordering is mixed up based on ordering of field #2, but it's working correctly. I was able to run a few iterations using this.

Answer (score 0):

Someone just upvoted my previous answer and so I had to invent a new solution, of course! This one's a bit better for two reasons:

1. it's pure `bash`, using a hash table instead of leaning on `awk`
2. you don't get garbage blank lines
3. it can take an arbitrary number of files to tack onto `tally` (three reasons)
4. the `tally` file can begin empty (four reasons)
5. it doesn't require a tempfile ("I didn't expect" etc.)

Save the following as `tally.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# define the associative array tally_table
declare -A tally_table
while read line ; do
    k=($line)
    [ -n "${k[1]}" ] && (( tot[${k[1]}] += ${k[0]} ))
done <<HERE
$(cat tally $@)
HERE
for i in "${!tally[@]}"; do
    echo "${tally[$i]} $i"
done > tally
cat tally
```

Try removing `tally` and create a new report file named `file` with a couple of lines:

```
1 Horse
3 Monkey
```

Then feed it in:

```
$ ./tally.sh file
3 Monkey
1 Horse
```

Now create another report named `newfile` with a couple of lines:

```
5 Horse
2 Pig
```

And feed it:

```
$ ./tally.sh newfile
3 Monkey
6 Horse
2 Pig
```

The `Horse` entry was correctly incremented. Sure, just as before the ordering isn't consistent. (I don't know how you'd sort for *Dog Cat Horse Goat ordering*, or where `Monkey` falls among them.)